# Creating workflow action, No response

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I have to ask about creating workflow in SharePoint website.

[image: When I create workflow]

It have some error as shown in the above picture.

And when I try to add action to the workflow, it shows no response as shown in below picture.

[image]

I want to know whether this issue is caused by the error or something else, how can I solve it ?

Comment: have you tried typing in the action ? what error is it giving? can you please elaborate your issue.

Comment: Did you get in touch with your server administrator to ask them why the workflow service is not configured on the server?

Comment: I have tried typing the action, after selection of the action, it shows the message (Start typing......Ribbon) again.

Comment: I have asked about why the workflow service is not configured on the server, but they also don't know why this issue appear :'(

Answer (score 3):

From the first picture, SharePoint2013 workflow is not available yet. It happens if you don't have workflow manager integrated in your SharePoint server.
If you have administrator access you can install and configure Workflow Manager 1.0. Here is a details [walk-through](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013-workflow-installing-and-configuring/#.VyhEznrvC5w) on it. Or you can contact with your server administrator to provide the service.

From the 2nd picture, can't get the problem. Please try to add action from action button which is given in ribbon of your SharePoint Designer. It should work for you current situation(with SharePoint 2010 workflow). If it won't work then please give me a feedback.

Comment: For the 2nd picture, here is a gif version to show my problem,Here is a gif about my problem:
http://makeagif.com/WXMwdQ
After clicking some action (e.g. Add time to Date in my gif), it give no response

Comment: Which version of SharePoint Designer you are using?

Comment: sharepoint designer 2013

Comment: Please, try to clear the SharePoint designer cache to check if it can work.


If that won't work then contact with your SharePoint server administrator that the SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features and workflows feature in the site collection features are currently enable or not. If they are not, then asked them to enable these features.

Comment: still can't work, but really thanks for your help :)

Comment: sorry, can't help much. If you get any solution of this problem, please let me know.